# Adding item form index of array to another array {Python}

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop

Hi i have file where i store domains name and expire dates for domains, i try get expire dates to array.

```
for i in array[2:2]:
    date_format = "%Y.%m.%d"
    b[i] = datetime.strptime(array[i], date_format)
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I'm beginner at python.
if sam one know how i can itterate by 2 on array and put items to new array

Comment: `array[2:2]` it will return null array or list. try to `print(array[2:2])`

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Python, list slicing follows the notation `my_list[start:stop)`. Therefore, if `start=stop`, then the returned list will be empty. For example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[1:1]
[]
```

I assume that you want to iterate through a `list` making 2 steps at a time. In this case, the following will do the trick:

```
for i in array[::2]:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b = []
for date in array[::2]:
    date_format = "%Y.%m.%d"
    b.append(datetime.strptime(date, date_format))
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to improve your answer

Comment: Thx i solve the problem  i use your example and i find if i wanna start from index 1 i make some think like this for date in array[1::2] its skip index[0] start from index[1] and itterate by 2